# Let A ⊂ R n be a closed rectangle and C ⊂ A. Then χC is integrable on A if and only if ∂C has measure 0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am trying to prove the theorem above and I'm not sure my proof is correct, χC is the indicator function of C.
I used the following theorem: Let A ⊂ $\mathbb{R}^2$
be a closed rectangle and f: A → R be bounded. Let B:= {x ∈ A | f is not continuous at x}. Then f is integrable if and only if B is a set of measure 0.

If χC is integrable, then the set B:= {x ∈A | f is not continuous at x} has measure zero. Since χC is continuous except for ∂C, we must have ∂C=B and so ∂C has measure zero.

Conversely, if ∂C has measure zero, since ∂C contains all points of discontinuity in A, ∂C=B. Therefore, B has measure zero and by the above theorem,χC is integrable.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is correct. The discontinuity set is exactly $\partial C$, so it has measure zero precisely when $\chi_C$ is Riemann integrable

Comment: Okay, thank you